# c# access to central data

Tags: c#, path

my Situation:
I've got a lot of Data which i need in every corner of my program. Something like Data Paths and so on. I need those informations in various classes.

What is the best way to implement that?

Sample:

```
 class A
{
    public string GetPath()
    {
        return "C:\\";
    }
}

class B
{
    private void sample()
    {
        A ab = new A();
        string path = ab.GetPath();
    }

}

class C
{
    private void sample()
    {
        A ab = new A();
        string path = ab.GetPath();
    }
}
```

So in my case i always need to initiate A and A always need to work inside the function "GetPath".

I want to prevent that the "GetPath"-Function always will be processed.

Comment: Look at static classes and singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like *dependency injection* may be a relevant concept to look into. There are lots of tools and frameworks to help you with advanced versions of this, but the core principle is as follows:

**Simplified example:**

An interface do declare what you need, without specifying how it will be provided:

```
interface IDataProvider {
    string GetPath();
}
```

An implementing class to provide it (could be completely different, so long as it implements the interface correctly):

```
public class DataProvider : IDataProvider(){

    private string _path = "";

    public GetPath()
    {  
        // Load only first time
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_path))
        {
            // You could return a hard-coded value, like this, or fetch
            // data in a more flexible way (config? DB? Web-service? ...?)
            _path = @"C:\..."; 
        }

        return _path;
    }
}
```

Now pass the implementation in *as an instance of the interface* wherever you need it:

```
class C {

    IDataProvider _dataProvider;

    public C(IDataProvider provider)
    {
        // This has no knowledge about DataProvider, it only cares
        // about this being an instance of an object that implements 
        // the signature "GetPath()":
        _dataProvider = provider;
    }

    private void Sample()
    {            
        string path = _dataProvider.GetPath();
    }
}
```

Now, from wherever you start up your project:

```
public class StartApp
{
    IDataprovider prov = new DataProvider();

    C myC = new C(prov);

    myC.Sample();

   // ..and similarly for other components, 
   // use the same Provider-instance:
   D yourD = new D(prov); 
   ED yourE = new E(prov);
}
```

You could also read config-values from files or a database, or whatever you like in `DataProvider`. The point here is to fetch the data once, and then use it everywhere via a shared instance.

Comment: also thanks for you answer. Is there any way to prevent that the "GetPath" function will be processed every time?

Comment: Perhaps you did not see my recent update? `GetPath()` will currently be run each time, but after the first time, the only operation it will perform is to check whether `_path` has been set. In other words, the main logic (loading `_path`) will only happen once.

Comment: oh my fault - didnt see that yet. Overall i think your solution matched ! Thank you very much! I think that your solution matches my idea :)

Answer (score 0):

As BWA says in comments, you should be using a static class for A. In example:

```
static class A
{
    public static string GetPath()
    {
        return "C:\\";
    }
}
```

A static class, function or variable is one where there is only one within the program, so can be accessed from anywhere. You cannot, however, declare instances of a static class. To access this function, use the following:

```
string path = A.GetPath();
```

If you need to declare instances of this class, use a static function or variable to store the path variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

What About encapsulate it before for more secure against sof exception.

not tested code

```
private string getPath;
public string GetPath
{
get => getPath; set => getPath=value;
}
```